# Tmux monitor activity change highlight color

Tags: tmux

I'm setting up my `tmux.conf` and I want to have the activity monitor with different colors. I would like to change the color of the highlight of the alerted window in the status bar.

The problem appears when I try to change the color of the background. I'm using this options shown from the `tmux` manual page.

```
# activity window
setw -g monitor-activity on
setw -g window-status-activity-bg red
setw -g window-status-activity-fg yellow
```

When I reload the configuration I can see that the color of the letters in the alerted window change to red but I can't find the way to change the highlight of the alerted window.

I'm using `tmux` version 1.6 and I also tried unsuccessfully on version 1.8.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be running into the fact that the default `window-status-activity-attr` is `reverse`. This ends up switching the foreground and background colors (i.e. you see red letters when you specified the `-bg` to be red).

Try adding this:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-activity-attr none
```

Or, try adjusting or switching your `window-status-activity-fg` and `window-status-activity-bg` settings.

Comment: With this options when I change the activity-bg the color of the background changes to the desired color but then the activity-fg (color of the letters) don't change (it's always white).

Comment: @Ionthas: It works for me with my old copy of *tmux* 1.6 (and my recent *master*-branch compiled version) under *iTerm 2*. It might have something to do with the terminal emulator you are using outside of *tmux*, or possibly the terminfo entry you are telling *tmux* to use to talk to that emulator. What is your outside terminal emulator, and what TERM are you using when attaching to *tmux*?

Comment: I'm using iTerm2 and screen-256color. I will try to use urxvt-256color.

Comment: I tried with xterm-256color and I also changed my solarized theme on iterm2 to the default theme. Still not working.

Comment: `screen-256color` is appropriate for inside *tmux*, but you should also make sure that you are using `xterm-256color` outside *tmux* (i.e. when attaching to or creating a session). Are you sure your *iTerm* color configuration has not been altered (`⌘I`, then the Colors tab)? A command like `bash -c 'for c in {0..15}; do tput setaf $c; echo colour$c; tput op; done'` (out/inside *tmux*, with `xterm-256color`/`screen-256color`) should show you this series of colors: black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, and white (then the “bright” versions of these colors; solarized changes all this).

Comment: It seems that all the colors inside and oustside tmux are correct. If I set the _activity-fg_ and _activity-bg_ to red an then change the red color with iTerm2 I only see the background color changing. It seems that for some reason the _activity-fg_ color is set on white. The funny thing is that if I change the white color with iTerm2 the color of the letters don't change.

Comment: I found that this line `setw -g window-status-format '#[fg=white] #W '` drives the behavior of the _activity-fg_ is this normal?

Comment: Maybe the white text you are seeing is iTerm’s foreground color; i.e. *tmux*’s `default`, not `white`/`colour7`. `window-status-format` is used for all inactive windows (an alerted window is necessarily inactive), so it makes sense that it would override the `window-status-activity-…` settings. It works like this (for an inactive window with an activity alert): first `window-status-{fg,bg,attr}` are applied, then (`window-status-activity-{fg,bg,attr}` are applied, then the string generated from `window-status-format` is output. The items that come later can always override the earlier items.

Comment: Using _window-status-fg_ to set the color instead of _window-status-format_ solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of **tmux 2.9** there is a new syntax for this:

```
# active window text color
set-window-option -ga window-status-activity-style fg=blue,bg=white
```

(Keep in mind that's backwards from what you'd expect:  'bg' is the text, 'fg' is the background.)